# Silverlight saving webcam image into the server folder

Tags: silverlight

I have created a silverlight project that captures the image through the webcam and stores it in my local hard, but I don't want to save it on the local hard I want to store it in my project folder then store the path in SQL database.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and save the image directly as a bitstream to the DB maybe?

```
private static ImageElementContract ImageToImageElementContract(Image image)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(image, null);
        ImageTools.ExtendedImage myImage = new ImageTools.ExtendedImage();
        myImage = ImageExtensions.ToImage(bmp);

        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

        JpegEncoder encoder = new JpegEncoder();
        encoder.Quality = 100;
        encoder.Encode(myImage, mStream);
        imageContract.ImageStream = mStream.ToArray();
        return imageContract;
    }
```

Should give you a stream, which you can pass to the DB and put back together if you need it again. It's hard to tell what your using it for. There's not much detail in your question

Comment: Thanx for replying sir..actually I need to capture the image from webcam which I have done..and then I need to save this captured image into the server folder..and its path in the database..I have tried a lot..but of no use...